# merging in C programming

Tags: c, merge

I am new in C programming and I'm faced with one error on my code. The error is:

> RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time: 340ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
>   This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a[4] = {5,9,13,18};
    int b[4] = {7,10,14,20};

    int i,j,k,l;
    i = 0; j = 0; k = 0;

    int result[8];

    while(i < 4 && j < 4){
        if(a[i]<b[i]) {
            result[k] = a[i]; k++; i++; 
        }
        else { result[k] = b[i]; k++; i++; }
    }

    while(i < 4){
        result[k] = a[i];
        k++; i++;
    }

    while(j < 4){
        result[k] = b[i];
        k++; i++;
    }

    for(l=0; l<8; l++){
        printf("Element[%d] : %d \n", l, result[l]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should be using `j` as the index for `b` in all cases. I.e., `b[j]` instead of `b[i]`. And then the `else` should increment `j` instead of `i`.

Comment: Step through the code in your debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Check the value of `k` before/after each while loop. You'll probably find you're running past `7` which means you're outside the bounds of the `result` array it's being used as an index for.

Comment: @Fred Larson Thank you very much I confused b[j] wth b[i]

Comment: You dont check if k >= 8 in your while loops. When k gets greater than 7 then the memory after `results` will be overwritten and you wille experience undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a separate index for each source array.  You are using only one and never incrementing the other, thereby overrunning the end of your destination array and invoking undefined behavior.

Two indices already exist in your code, but you haven't used `j` properly. Your code should look something like this:

```
   while(i < 4 && j < 4){
        if(a[i]<b[j]) {
            result[k] = a[i]; k++; i++; 
        }
        else {
            result[k] = b[j]; k++; j++;
        }
    }
```

You need a similar change in the while loop on `j`.

As a matter of style, I'd also take advantage of the postincrement operator, which is pretty idiomatic in C:

```
   while(i < 4 && j < 4){
        if(a[i]<b[j]) {
            result[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        else {
            result[k++] = b[j++];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

U should use j as index. Use b[j] instead of b[i]